# Crystal Report: Custom Order By

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sql-order-by

I have a working crystal report and it called from a VB application. I want the report to be sorted according to specific column values. Consider the following example,

```
Model-Type     Model-Code     Quantity

A              xxx-123-xA1    1
A              xxx-123-xA2    1
B              xxx-123-xB1    1
B              xxx-123-xB2    1
C              xxx-123-xC1    1
C              xxx-123-xC2    1
```

Through crystal report, I can sort Model-Type in either ascending order or descending order. Is there any way I can sort it in a customized way like Model-Type "B" first then "A" and then "C" (for business purposes)?? I can do it through SQL using CASE in ORDER BY clause. But how can this be done in Crystal Report. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you create a group on the column, in the group options box, on the common tab, select "in a specified order" from the dropdown box

alternatively create a formula like:

```
if {table.value} = 'B' then 1
else if {table.value} = 'A' then 2
else if {table.value} = 'C' then 3
```

etc... then you can sort on that formula field instead